# Have any fonts been released that are based on slender gold?

Tags: characters, fonts

I remember the first time I saw [slender gold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aSonghuizong.jpg) I had something like an 'am I dreaming?' moment. That's not how characters were supposed to look! The lines aren't supposed to cross, etc., etc.

But wait, it actually looked better than characters were supposed to look. The same way grass script makes kaiti look 'uptight', 瘦金體 makes kaiti look 'lazy', and clerical look 'boring'.

At this point, one year down the line, slender gold is my favorite calligraphy style. In fact, I am trying to learn it, and I wish that everything I printed out in chinese could be in slender gold. Is there a slender gold font?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can download them at:

http://www6.flash8.net/font/2933.shtml (traditional)

http://www6.flash8.net/font/4101.shtml (simplified)

If you like this kind of style, you may also be interested in [鋼筆書法](http://bit.ly/rRl7eK)

Comment: I'm already getting the Simplified one! :D Is "鋼筆書法" free too or is it for purchase? It looks good. :) +1 by the way.

Comment: @Alenanno 鋼筆書法 just means "fountain pen calligraphy." It's not a single style. I suspect there are fountain pen calligraphy styled fonts out there.

Comment: Ah, I apologize for my lack of knowledge. :D Now that you say it, I recognize some characters...